# NGINX shows raw CSS code instead of rendering it

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm trying to deploy my flask application on my VM, on docker containers while using NGINX to serve static files. But when I spin up everything and go to my app in the browser I only get the raw CSS code I am trying to host, NGINX doesn't render it.

[image: Here is a screenshot of what Im seeing]

Here is my nginx config

```
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  main.css;
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    }
```

And here is my docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 5000

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Comment: CSS is plain text, how should the browser render that if not as plain text? CSS is **applied** to HTML or XML, but not "viewable" as single file...

Answer (score 1):

Looks Like there is only CSS given to the nginx indexes, without index.html it can not produce the Viewable content. make sure there is a Flask route added inside your Flask app with `static_url_path`.